# find and count strings in sentence like rows of dataframe: python

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to find some strings in a dataframe.I seperated the column WHICH I wanted to search in and named it 'g'.SO i called JUST one column of my dataframe as g. and each row of g is like a dictionary that is in a list .i cant find my strings and count them.note that there is at most one of the specified string in each row of 'g' and it is in a sentence. a typical row of g is like:

```
 [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]
```

and the type of it is object.
my code:

```
for i in g:
if 'Comedy' in i:
    c+=1
elif 'Action' in i:
    ac+=1
```

and the error:

```
     14 for i in g:
---> 15     if 'Comedy' in i:
     16         c+=1
     17     elif 'Action' in i:

TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

Comment: please paste the complete error and a reproducible example.

Comment: for examp line 0 of g is:' name is Comedy' i want to count the rows that contain those specific strings

Comment: you are trying to iterate over a column that has floats and are trying to check if a string is in a float. that's why there was an error.

Comment: where are the floats?

Comment: from your edit, each row in the column g of your dataframe has a string that starts with { and ends with }. or is g the name of your column or dataframe?

Comment: as i said g is the name of a column of a dataframe

Comment: look i called a whole column of my dataframe as g. and each row of g is like a dictionary that is in list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping over the column to be searched, it would be more efficient (and easier to read) to instead utilise [`str.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to generate a mask based on the sub-strings you want to count within your DataFrame, apply this to your DataFrame and finally run `count()` to count the length of this filtered response.

Assuming that you want to count occurrences of `'Comedy'` in the `'name'` column of `df`.

```py
c_mask = df['name'].dropna().str.contains('Comedy')
c = df['name'].dropna()[c_mask].count()
```

Note that `dropna()` is used to filter out any `numpy.nan` values in the target column that would result in a non Boolean Series - which would not be suitable for masking - being returned. It is called again before mask application to ensure proper compatibility of dimensions. Changes here will not be reflected in the underlying `df` object.

If you're going to be repeating this procedure a lot for different sub-strings, it may be an idea to write a function to return the count of specific sub-string occurrences in a given column.

e.g

```py
def count_sub(df, col, s):
    mask = df[col].dropna().str.contains(s)
    return df[col].dropna()[mask].count()
```

This function will return a numeric value representing the number of times that `s` is present within values of the `df` column named `col`.

The above examples could be handled fine in a single line, however they are spread across two here in attempts to maximise readability for those unused to such an approach.

Comment: tnx alot bro,but when i use your code, it says:Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values

Comment: @BerylAmend Updated my answer to remedy this using `dropna()` during mask creation and application. Solutions provided now properly account for `numpy.nan` values - apologies for the initial oversight.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your problem is, but base on your code and description, I guess it can be solved using the following approach.

```py
c = df['col_name'].str.contains('Comedy').values.sum()
ac = df['col_name'].str.contains('Action').values.sum()
```

Here `col_name` is the name of your column and `df` is the name of the DataFrame.

Comment: tnx but it gives nan as result,while there are alot of them.

Comment: @BerylAmend is `[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]` a string?

Comment: @BerylAmend This solution relies upon summing Boolean values returned by `df['col_name'].str.contains(target_string)` - `True== 1` and `False==0` so summing these works fine to count occurrences of `target_string` if all values are Boolean - however it fails where any values in `df['col_name']` are `np.nan` as the truth value of `np.nan` is itself `np.nan` and any mathematical operation involving such a value will also return `np.nan`.

Comment: @JPI93 Didn't take that into account, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: If that is the case, `c = df['g'].dropna().str.contains('Comedy').values.sum()` would work.

Comment: @icheft No worries, `np.nan` is brilliant but can be a real thorn in the side if not accounted for. Correct, using `dropna()` to remove offending rows before `str.contains()...` does make this approach viable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value count for the name column, you can simply use the `.count()` method to get the count of all unique names in your dataframe column.

For instance, reproducing your dataframe like:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID"   : [35, 10749, 14, 15],
    "name" : ["Comedy", "Romance", "Comedy", "Comedy"]
})
```

Then you can simply use the in-built function as `data.groupby("name")["ID"].count()` which will list out the count of all the unique name in your dataframe.

**EDIT** Modified the dataframe with your given data. You can run commands like `data.head()` to view the data. I think you should look into the documentation, link in the comment :)

Comment: when i write 'data.groupby("genres")["Comedy"].count()', it says: 'Column not found: Comedy'

Comment: You have to count based on your column name `name`. I think you should check the [official pandas groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) documentation too.